# Will searching a text with grep results in copying files in SSHFS

Tags: grep, sshfs

I have linked a remote directory using SSHFS and now if i search some text within there files will SSHFS copy files to my local space..I know when we try to see the content of the files in SSHFS it will copy the file in local drive.

Comment: Can you post the command you are running?